# where to place the struts.xml file

Tags: struts2

I need to know...where we have to place the struts.xml file...Is there any possibilities of changing the location of struts.xml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, it is looked for in the classpath's root level.

Place yours directly under `WEB-INF/classes` (or to a place where someone/something grabs it and puts it there, typically the root of a source folder, such as `src/main/resources` if you are using Maven).

Another option would be to have it packaged at the root level of a JAR in your `WEB-INF/lib`. A struts.xml in `WEB-INF/classes` gets precedence though. I have yet to come across an example where this option would make sense though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple dynamic web project, I recommend putting it under the src folder. This is because it simply works. You can create a classes folder underneath the WEB-INF folder and move it there as well.